# How can I write a trigger to detect when a terran building burns to its death? (Starcraft 2)

Tags: scripting, modding, starcraft-2

I'm working with Starcraft 2 Map Editor, and am having a little bit of a trigger problem.

It's quite easy to detect when a specific unit kills a structure (simply check if triggering unit == whatever) but I'm not quite sure how to tell when a building dies to to either fire (terran buildings) or bleeding out (zerg buildings when off creep).

What condition should I be looking for in my "a unit dies" trigger to see if one of those two situations occured?

PS: Sorry for lack of available tags!

Comment: This seems better for the gaming SE maybe? Its a fine line, but there might be more expertise over there.

Comment: Should be at http://gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: Noctrine, the community there has said it's not on topic for them: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here and the discussion on our meta points to yes: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here, reopening.

Comment: @Tetrad, it feels so weird. But after reading the gaming communities thread I agree.

Comment: I think it feels weird because its far more likely that someone in that community (with their vast array of StarCraft questions/answers) will probably be able to answer this better than us.

Comment: "Use map settings" from SC1 and now Custom maps on SC2 is a real game development community that have innovated in a lot of game-plays. I don't see why this would be off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a behavior for Terran buildings that applies the burning effect periodically if the building's health is below 1/3. To see if a building is killed by this effect, you could do this:

```
Events
    Unit - Any Unit takes Fatal Any damage (from Any effects)
Local Variables
Conditions
    (Damaging effect) == BurndownDamage (Unnamed)
    (Unit type of (Triggering unit)) == <building>
```

Edit: I forgot the zerg building part, but it's exactly the same but with a different effect:

```
    (Damaging effect) == ZergBuildingNotOnCreepDamage (Unnamed)
```

Comment: Ha, how soon after my own answer did you post this? :P

Comment: I read the post and then opened the editor and looked it up, then typed up my reply and submitted it and saw yours there. So pretty much right after :P.

Answer (score 1):

I've been poking around. I've determined that every terran building has an effect "Terran Burn Down" or some such, that I assume is what is actually causing the damage.

I'm not sure of the specifics, exactly, but I imagine one of two things should be possible:

- The building counts as its own killer (because its death is related to an effect it 'owns')
- The death can be tracked by attributing it to the effect, something along the lines of "Unit dies" Condition: Killing Effect == Terran Burn Down.

I imagine the zerg buildings have a similar 'requires creep' ability.

I'll keep investigating and keep this open in case someone can provide a fuller answer.